# How do I compare a double quotes string to a character?

Tags: c++, string, char, comparison

I have tried to compare a string subscript to a string with a space (" ") in c++, but it returned a pointer comparison error. Now when I try comparing " " to ' ', obviously it doesn't equal. The code below is supposed to continue the for loop when a certain subscript of the string is equal to a space character.

If I compare the substring to " ", I get this error:
`16:22: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]`

Note that when I input a space into the input variable it needs to compare it.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
 
using namespace std;
 
int main()
{
    string input;
    vector<int> letters (26,0);
    vector<char> alpha = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
    bool flag;
    cin >> input;
    for(int i = 0; i < input.size();i++){
        if(input[i]==' '){
            continue;
        }
        cout << i;
        
        for(int j = 0; j < alpha.size(); j++){
            if(input[i]==alpha[j]){
                letters[j] ++;
            }
        }
    }
     
    for (int i = 0; i < letters.size();i++){
        if(letters[i] > 0){
            cout << alpha[i] << ": " << letters[i] << endl;
        }
    }
   
   
}
```

Is there any way to compare a space character with a string?

Comment: Can you point out where you're getting an error? Your code seems fine to me: https://ideone.com/X6aYxt  It is worth noting though that as it is written right now you'll never have a space in your input because `cin >> input;` will stop at the first whitespace it finds.

Comment: Also, what do you *actually* want to do?

Comment: Which line is getting that error? I don't see anything that compares with `" "`.

Comment: i wrote the actual question below the code

Comment: `if(input[i]==' ')` is the correct way to do it, why do you think you need to use a string instead?

Comment: Have you tried isspace( ) function?

Comment: Do you want to compare `" "` and `' '`?

Comment: since the input is a string, comparing anything in the input variable with a char type will result in a false equality

Comment: The input can be anything: you may read just a single character.

Comment: use getline to check for space

Comment: If you want to compare the whole input instead of just one character, you write `if (input == " ")`

Comment: "comparing anything in the input variable with a char type will result in a false equality" That doesn't make any sense. A string is a collection of characters.

Comment: i have tested it and it never detects the space if i put it in the input...meaning that a string " " is different from char ' '

Comment: But like he said above, it will never contain a space because `cin >> input` reads one space-separated word into the variable.

Comment: Your code never detects a space because as you have written it you can never input a space. You probably want the `getline` function. `>>` will not read whitespace by default.

Answer (score -1):

As I know, there isn't way to make `'s' == "s"` work. But you can make `'s' == string("s")` work by defining `operator==`:

```cpp
// for 's'==string("s")
bool operator==(const char c, const string &s) { return c == s[0]; } 
// for string("s") == 's'
bool operator==(const string &s, const char c) { return c == s[0]; }
```

And it would work.

Comment: as i said in the question, strings and chars cannot equal each other whether or not they have the same thing inside